# Ionic2: backbutton disabled after login

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

Ionic2: When user login it redirect to dashboard but if he used backbutton they redirect to login. How to restricted to backbutton to not redirect user to login. And also when user logout backbutton again route to dashboard. please help me!

Answer (score 0):

how are you redirecting the user to the dashboard? I think you are using push() from navCtrl. If that is the case, then try using setRoot() from navController like this,

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
```

This helps you in removing the back button

Comment: thanks friends. I solved this problem already by using setRoot method.